# Facebook authentication is raising an error on rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, devise, omniauth

I setup a rails app (3.2.3 *[devise 3.4.1, omniauth facebook 2.0.0, omniauth 1.2.2]*) to use facebook as authenticator and I'm facing this issue when I try to log in. The problem is, it doesn't even reach my code (controllers). Do you have any idea about this?

It's strange that when I set `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com` at hosts and I browse to `mydomain.com:3000` it works! Although locally I'm using `http` instead of `https` like production.

```
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for x.x.x.x at 2015-02-12 00:45:05 +0000
Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=xxxx" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-12 00:45:05 +0000

URI::InvalidURIError (the scheme http does not accept registry part: app_server (or bad hostname?)):
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb:84:in `initialize'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:214:in `new'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:214:in `parse'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:416:in `full_host'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was an issue with nginx proxy, I forgot to forward the `Host` header for a given location. I just set the header host and everything went fine.

`proxy_set_header Host 'example.com';`